# Does a new site installation run through hook_updates of every module?

Tags: 7, updating

I have an existing D7 website for which i write hook_updates whenever i have to make any changes to the schema. Now, i have altered the taxonomy_term_data table using one such update. My question is if I install this website in another Schema(Database) will it automatically make those changes to taxonomy_term_data?
Or, do i need to make those changes again explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install a module, the largest number found in `hook_update_N` hook will be stored in the `system` table's `schema_version` field. It will not run the function. Just stored in the table.

When you copy a module to a new site, any of the `hook_update_N` hooks will **not** be executed for you. However, if you would like to make any change, you can implement `hook_install` to make the necessary database or any other changes.